# C array values change as a result of printf statement?

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I am trying to write a program that prints the even divisors of whatever number is entered by the user. For some reason, when the user enters 10 and the program prints out:

```
 10 is evenly divisible by:
1, 3, 2, 27, logout
```

I have no idea where it is getting these numbers from. If I uncomment the second to last printf statement, I get the following:

```
10 is evenly divisible by:
i = 0
1, i = 1
2, i = 2
5, i = 3
32767, logout
```

Why is it doing this?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void ) {

    int n, i, leng = 0, arr[leng];

    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%i",&n);

    printf("%i is evenly divisible by:\n", n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            arr[leng] = i;
            leng++;
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i <= leng; i++) {
        printf("i = %i\n", i);
        printf("%i, ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you set the lenght of arr to be leng which you set to 0. This is going to break, you need to allocate it to be n/2 or similar

Comment: `leng = 0, arr[leng];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n, i, leng = 0, arr[leng];
```

You declare an array of length 0 and then merrily write past its end. C- Arrays do not grow dynamically of their own. Hence, you corrupt (stack) memory and hence you find surprising behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of `leng` does not cause the array `arr` to be magically resized.   `arr` is being created - once, at the point of definition - as an array of zero elements (not particularly useful) and never being resized from there.

All that is happening is that multiple values are being written to an array with zero elements.  That is undefined behaviour.   Usually in the form of overwriting memory that is adjacent to the location of that array .... which may contain variables or other program data.